# Слова, различающиеся одной согласной буквой

Tags: общие-вопросы

Цель темы: розыск каких-либо вспомогательных материалов для упрощения поиска слов, различающихся одной согласной буквой (например: игра/икра, город/голод, конь/вонь и т.д.), независимо от их принадлежности к той или иной части речи.

Что можно по этому вопросу найти? Быть может, имеются словари такого характера, либо электронные библиотеки, или же кто-то встречал специализированное программное обеспечение, способное выявлять подобные случаи?

P.S. Вероятно, кто-то вспомнит софт в духе "Помощник кроссвордиста", но это неудачный вариант, поскольку он предполагает, что пользователю заведомо известны некоторые буквы и их количество в искомом слове.

Comment: Была (или есть) такая игра в слова, в которой надо из одного слова сделать другое путём последовательного изменения одной буквы, причём после каждого хода должно получаться "нормальное" слово.  Помню, видел как из "мухи" делали "слона", из "теста" - "булку" и т.п.

Comment: Кстати, про словари не знаю, но программного обеспечения для играющих в "Эрудит" ("Scrabble") всякого полно, там есть n-буквенные слова и проч.

Answer (score 1):

Извините, не достаточно репутации, чтобы прокомментировать, поэтому напишу ответом, хотя это и не есть ответ на данный вопрос, а всего-лишь возможное решение.

Если есть возможность добыть базу данных всех слов (например крупный словарь в электронном виде), то возможно написать не сильно сложную программу, которая бы прошерстила массив и нашла для Вас совпадения с необходимыми различиями.

Такую программу сможет написать любой студент старших курсов, **учащийся** на программиста.

Comment: Меняю ваш словарь на свою программу. Написана лет двадцать назад. Поиск по базе отличий от образца любого уровня. Словарь в 50К слов бьет на два отличия мгновенно. С++. Портабельна.

Comment: Спасибо. Такая мысль была. И в другой теме мне порекомендовали взять словарь http://speakrus.ru/dict/index.htm. В программах не силён, но с чужой помощью попытался реализовать эту идею на VBS. Неудача. @behemothus, если Ваша программа подходит для решения данной задачи, буду признателен за возможность ей воспользоваться. Словарь же я качал по ссылке выше. Более полного не нашёл.

Comment: Какой из них? Туи же проблема в том, что словарь должен быть "чистеньким", содержать только существительные и проч. То, что лежало на полках спикруса явно не пригодно для этой цели. Не знаю, сейчас может, что-то изменилось. Касательно программы. В ближайших архивах у меня была именно версия поиска "похожих" слов. Остальное, как вы понимаете, потребует переделки. Дальнейшую связь лучше держать по почте. Мой адрес - в профиле.

Comment: Хорошо. Я напишу вам.Благодарю.